# How to pass a class instance to a service using putExtra

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have a class that uses a class instance of `import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel` but now i want to pass that class instance to a Service where i can call it, but i cant get around it.

I have tried using putExtra but i cant seem to find a way to get it from the service end.

For example:

```
Intent playIntent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), MusicPlayerService.class);
playIntent.putExtra("activeAudioUrl", activeAudio);
playIntent.putExtra("channelInstance", channel);
activity.startService(playIntent);
```

Here is the service class from which i am trying to get the data:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String activeAudio = intent.getStringExtra("activeAudioUrl");
    MethodChannel methodChannel = intent.getParcelableExtra("channelInstance");

    ...
}
```

Comment: Basically if you want to pass a class in an intent, the class needs to implement the `Parcelable` interface. But, I doubt you want to pass an instance of `MethodChannel` in an intent. You will be leaking data associated to the channel. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Does `MethodChannel` implements `Parcelable`? On the other hand you can bind Service and set the instance with `Binder`..

Comment: no MethodChannel does not implement `Parcelable`

Comment: How do i bind the service, please can you show a code sample. I'm new to java i am trying to create a plugin for a framework that needs to work with android.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958561/how-to-navigate-to-another-page-but-show-information-according-to-the-items-on-m) method can solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class containing your data to be passed and extend/implement that from `Serializable` or `Parcelable` and then you can put an object of that class as an `Extra` to your `Intent` and use it in your `Service`.
In this class you creat your data, pass them and then retrieve them.
For creating your custom Parcelable class you can see these following links:

[1.stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/9944300)

[2.medium](https://medium.com/@nikhildhyani365/understand-parcelable-in-android-27ce420d695b)

And according to [this link](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/) it's better to use Parcelable.

So, create a class that implement the Parcelable (e.g. name this class `DataToSend`), you can use constructor to pass your data and use getter for retrieving your data.

Edit => Now `DataToSend` is already implements `Parcelable` and all you have to do is :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
DataToSend dataToSend = new DataToSend(activeAudio, channel);
bundle.putParcelable("data", dataToSend);
Intent playIntent = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext(), 
MusicPlayerService.class);
playIntent.putExtra(bundle);
activity.startService(playIntent);
```

and for retrieving data :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String activeAudio = intent.getStringExtra("activeAudioUrl");
    MethodChannel methodChannel = intent.getParcelableExtra("channelInstance");
    Bundle b = intent.getExtra();
    DataToSend data = (DataToSend) b.getParcelable("data");

    // Here you can retrieve your data(channel & activeAudio) from following
    // data object. (e.g. data.getAudio())
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass non-data objects over an IPC boundary by calling startService(). What you are actually doing here is calling ActivityManager which is a system service running in a different process to start a service in your process for you. What you can do instead is put the MethodChannel reference in a place reachable both from the service and a place where you're starting it, for example by using dependency injection.